# Force relationships on django models for models that aren't officially FK related

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to figure out how to get the django admin system to display my models as inlines, when there isn't a direct FK from child to parent model.

I have three models (pseudo code):

```
class CampaignMain(models.model):
    ...

class CampaignMonitor(models.model): 
    campaign = models.OneToOneField(CampaignMain, pk=True)

class CampaignTransaction(models.model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(CampaignMain)
```

So both CampaignMonitor and CampaignTransaction FK CampaignMain, which is the way I need it to be structured.

Here's the bit I can't fathom:  I need an admin page showing CampaignMonitor with CampaignTransaction as inlines.  But when I try this, I get "error no fk in CampaignTransaction pointing to CampaignMonitor"

Is there a way to "force" the relationship just for the admin page? Or is there a generic FK option?  I saw something in contrib/contenttypes, but it doesn't seem to be what I need. Or am I going to have to build a custom admin section to two models in that way?

As always advice is greatly appreciated.

imanc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of OneToOneField you can use [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), which implemented using a one-to-one relationshinp:

```
class CampaignMonitor(CampaignMain): 
    ...
```

Now modify CampaignMonitor's admin as needed for your needs.